# Going to main Scene when back from background

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

when app back to background i have at the delegate this :

```
if( [navController_ visibleViewController] == director_ )
     [director_ resume];
```

Now if i was at `ccscene 2` when i have entered to background, when i am back, it goes to `scene2`.

I want to define the home scene, that each time we comes from background we go there from the delegate .

How would i do that ?

Comment: why not just change the scene when appdelegate receives didenterforeground?

Comment: how? i have to override these commands ?

Comment: implement appdelegate willenterforeground http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html and call director' replaceScene there